# Удаление репозитория с github'a

Tags: github

Это вообще возможно -- удалить ставший не нужным репозиторий с github?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

настройки репозитория - удалить репозиторий (последняя опция) - ввести название репозитория

Answer (score 15):

1. Заходим в аккаунт
2. Выбираем репозиторий который хотим удалить
3. Заходим в репозиторий
4. Выбираем в меню "Settings" (рис.)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Скроллим страницу вниз, выбираем блок "Danger Zone", 
   кнопка "Delete this repository" (рис.)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. В строке прописываем название репозитория на удаление: (рис.)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
7. Подтверждаем

   - Если запросит код, вводим свой код аккаунта.Все.