# Как с GitHub удалить репозиторий ? Пункт меню Setting отсутствует

Tags: github

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с GitHub можно удалить репозиторий, находясь в самом ГитХаб ?  Все рекомендации сводятся к переходу в пункт Setting, однако в настоящее время пункт меню Setting  отсутствует. Возможно, связано с обновленной версией. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете сделать скрин, где у вас нет кнопки `Settings`?

Comment: Скрин с отсутствующей кнопкой setting выложил.

Comment: Ну так вы не залогинились.

Comment: да, точно, сорян.

Comment: А как быть, если сделал форк репозитория, и теперь хочу удалить его - но у меня отсутствует кнопка settings. Я авторизован.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удаление репозитория с github'a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/333411/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-githuba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала надо авторизоваться и дальше переходите на страницу вашего репозитория